# Aplicação da variável variável

Tags: php

Visualizei uma aula sobre variável variável em PHP e me surgiu a seguinte dúvida, qual a aplicação deste formato variável variável? se não for pedir muito, um exemplo simples e prático. Agradecido!

Comment: Quase nenhuma. Uso PHP faz um bom tempo e nunca precisei utilizá-la - e todas as vezes que vi alguém usando era de forma desnecessária, geralmente para não ter o trabalho de refazer da maneira *correta*.

Comment: Thalles, só gostaria de avisar que o sistema penaliza usuários que criam e excluem múltiplas perguntas. Percebi que criou algumas perguntas que não foram bem recebidas e que prontamente você as excluiu. Cuidado com isso. Algumas delas inclusive provavelmente seriam fechadas, ou por serem amplas, não claras ou fora do escopo do site. Se ainda tiver alguma dúvida quanto ao site, pode acessar a [help]; ou quando tiver 20 pontos de reputação, será bem-vindo no [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha).